# Reading spaces from file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following code which reads text from a file and stores the characters in a vector. However this code is not reading spaces and pushing them in the vector. I tried to use myRf>>noskipws but its not working.

```
int a;

    int b;
int outp;

if (myRF.is_open())
    {
        while (!myRF.eof())
        {
            myRF >> a;
            myRF >> b;
// myRf>>noskipws
            for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
            {
                vector <char> col; 
                for (int j=0; j<b; j++)
                {   

                     myRF>>outp;
                     col.push_back(outp);
                }

                grid.push_back(col);
            }
        }
    }
    myRF.close();
```

Comment: printing a and b prints the actual number listed in the file. The only problem im having is reading spaces, reading of contents is exactly how I require it to work.

Answer (score 1):

When you enable `std::noskipws` leading whitespace isn't skipped. However, you try to read an `int` which can't start with a space! You should read a variable of type `char` to read, well, `char`s. That should just work.

Note that it is much faster to read `char`s using `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`:

```
std::istream::kerberos(myRF);
if (kerberos) {
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(myRF, true), end;
    while (it = end /* && other condition */) {
        char c = *it;
        ++it;
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

BTW, do **not** `myRF.eof()` to control the loop! That doesn't work because the stream cannot predict what you will try to read! The `eof()` member is only useful to determine why a read failed and distinguish between legit reason (have reached te end of the file) and broken input. Instead, read and check the result, e.g.

```
while (myRF >> a >> b) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the >> operator uses white space to determine when to end the stream extraction.  If you want to grab every character from a file and store the separately then you would use something like this:

```
std::vector<char> letters;
std::ifstream fin ("someFile.txt");
char ch;

while (fin.get(ch))
    letters.push_back(ch);
```